# DataTableReader not updating

Tags: c#, ado.net

In VS 2012, I have created a DataTableReader for reading an existing DataTable. The DataTable is configured to run a query against a SQLServer database.  When I view the DataTable in DataSet designer and choose Preview Data, I get an appropriately populated table.  However, when I try to view it with a DataTableReader within my code, it is returning as having no rows. Here's the code:

```
DataTableReader reader = this.myDataSet.myDataTable.CreateDataReader();
reader.Read();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
       }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("reader returned no rows");
}
```

Putting a breakpoint at reader.HasRows line (or right after) tells me that HasRows is false. The DataTableReader appears to be making a good connection to the database, ie it is not erroring out, but it is not returning rows that I know are there. Can you help me figure out why the DataTable 'Preview Data' from DataSet Designer works but not from within the code?

Comment: How do you populate the data into your datatable?

Comment: The backend table (on SQLServer) was originally populated via another application that had a connection to SQLServer. Occasionally, updates are made directly via SSMS.

Comment: ok, can you show us the code used to fill the datatable?